# Azure cli authentication with BlobServiceClient

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-python-sdk, azureclicredential

Should it be possible to use cli authentication with Azure storage?

```
cli_auth = AzureCliAuthentication()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net", credential=cli_auth)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("mycontainer")

blobs=container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob)
```

Right now I get:

> Exception has occurred: ClientAuthenticationError Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the
> www-authenticate header. ErrorCode:InvalidAuthenticationInfo
> authenticationerrordetail:Audience validation failed. Audience did not
> match.

Comment: When run locally, DefaultAzureCredential relies on environment variables named
**AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate-hosted-applications. **AzureCliCredential** is one of the methods called. Your question does not show what **AzureCliAuthentication** does or what library it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will have to use `AzureCLICredentials` instead of using `AzureCLIAuthentication`.**

You can use something like below after doing a `az login` :

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
cli_auth = AzureCliCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<Storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net", credential=cli_auth)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<ContainerName>")

blobs=container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce the error message using AzureCliCredential as well.

Comment: Same here. I get the error This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Comment: I was the owner of the subscription but that was not enough. I added myself to the role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" and now it works!